# Sum a column in Crystal Report and When is Empty Sum = 0

Tags: crystal-reports, sum

I want to Sum a column in Crystal Report, but when the column is empty it does not show the sum = 0

This Is Formula

```
if isnull(Sum ({VSalesIncome.TotalPrice}))
then 0
else
Sum ({VSalesIncome.TotalPrice})
```

This Is Error

```
error in Formula Sum Price :
isnull(Sum ({VSalesIncome.TotalPrice}))
A number field or currency amount field is required here 
Details errorkind:
```

Answer (score 1):

Sum ignores null values, so simply sum...

Or if you insist on checking for null, use a detail level formula:

```
if isnull({VSalesIncome.TotalPrice}) then 0 else {VSalesIncome.TotalPrice}
```

and then sum that formula.

Comment: Sum not found in formula

Comment: And when value sum price is null show erorr
Erorr in formula sum price : if isnull({VSalesIncome.TotalPrice}) then 0 else {VSalesIncome.TotalPrice} a number is requierd here , details errorkind

Comment: Sounds like {VSalesIncome.TotalPrice} is not numeric.